# Passing table name from a list of tables to a SELECT query

Tags: sql-server

My organisation will soon be receiving a varying number of datasets every month which our Data Services team loads each dataset into their own table i.e. 47 files submitted, 47 tables in the database. Not a pretty approach but it will be improved in time. The year and month of submission is part of the table name. i.e. CMorgNZ322_200701PLD ….. NZ322_200701 being the variable part of the table name; NZ322X is the origin of the data and 200701 being April 2007 (based on financial year)

I don’t want to be a slave to editing a SELECT query just to amend the table name month after month so I want to write a stored procedure that passes the table name from one SELECT query to a 2nd SELECT query

This is my first foray into using LOOPS so I’m wondering what is the best approach and how do I pass the table name into the 2nd SELECT query from the initial SELECT query

```
DECLARE cur_filestoprocess 
DECLARE @vcYrMth VarChar(6)
SET @vcYrMth = ‘200701’

SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ‘CMOrg%’ + @vcYrMth + ‘PLD’;

SELECT  COLa,
        COLb,
        COLc,
        COLd,
        SUM(COLg) AS ‘Activity’,
        SUM(COLk) AS ‘Costs’
INTO    RegionABC200701Summary
FROM  tablename1
GROUP BY COLa,
         COLb,
         COLc,
         COLd
```

In advance, thanks for your help…..

Comment: and your question/problem is what exact ?

Comment: You will have to use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dynamic SQL this might not be the most elegant but you should get the idea

```
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @vcYrMth VARCHAR(6)
SET @vcYrMth = '200701'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp;

SELECT TABLE_NAME
INTO #tmp
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'CMOrg%' + @vcYrMth + 'PLD'

DECLARE @rowNum INT
SET @rowNum = 0

DECLARE @length INT
SELECT @length = COUNT(*) FROM #tmp

WHILE (@rowNum < @length)
BEGIN

    SELECT @tableName = TABLE_NAME
    FROM #tmp
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME OFFSET @rowNum ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

    SELECT @sql = 'SELECT  COLa,
                COLb,
                COLc,
                COLd,
                SUM(COLg) AS ‘Activity’,
                SUM(COLk) AS ‘Costs’
           INTO    Region'+@tableName+'Summary
           FROM  tablename1
           GROUP BY COLa,
                 COLb,
                 COLc,
                 COLd'
    FROM #tmp

    --PRINT (@sql)
    EXEC (@sql)

    SET @rowNum = @rowNum + 1
END
```

**Edited**
The above will only work for SQL 2012 and above, use this snippet if using a version below

Replace

```
SELECT @tableName = TABLE_NAME
FROM #tmp
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME OFFSET @rowNum ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

With

```
SELECT @tableName = TABLE_NAME
FROM (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) AS RowNumber
    FROM #tmp
    ) a
WHERE RowNumber = @rowNum
```

Comment: Ah. Brilliant. I see now, how I need to proceed. Many, many thanks